# Semantic markup & responsive design – How to proceed in this specific situation?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, semantics

I am building a small website using the mobile first approach, meaning I start with a small screen and gradually get bigger. To save place, I show/hide some information on page or substitute the information depending on screen size. While this might look cool, it really gives me a headache trying to keep the markup as semantic as possible.
Let's dive in, this is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <a href="#navlist">☰</a>
        <a href="/">Page Title</a>
        <p class="hidden-s hidden-l">I the page's tagline</p>
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Close Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<main role="main">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1><a href="#">Blog Post 1</a></h1>
        </header>
        <p>Short excerpt of Blog Post 1</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1><a href="#">Blog Post 2</a></h1>
        </header>
        <p>Short excerpt of Blog Post 2</p>
    </article>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
nav { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4); }

#navlist {
    display:none;
}

#navlist:target {
    display:block;
}

.hidden-s {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .hidden-s {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .hidden-l {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW4hs/)

You see, the tagline is hidden on small screens, shown on middle size screens and hidden again for larger screens. I hide the tagline on large screens because I want to add a bit more info in a different place on larger screens, like so:

**HTML**

```
<main role="main">
<div class="more-info">
    <header>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <p>Some more info over the page you are reading.</p>
    </header>
</div>
<article>
    <header>
        <h1><a href="#">Blog Post 1</a></h1>
    </header>
    <p>Short excerpt of Blog Post 1</p>
</article>
<article>
    <header>
        <h1><a href="#">Blog Post 2</a></h1>
    </header>
    <p>Short excerpt of Blog Post 2</p>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden-s,
.more-info {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .hidden-l {
        display: none;
    }

    .more-info {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Yc5/)

Now the problem is the `header` element. Let me quote [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element):

> When the nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element is the body element, then it applies to the whole page.

So by wrapping the `nav` inside a `header`, I basically say that the nav and it's contents is suitable for the whole page, is this true? Because at the same time, I feel that putting the `nav` inside the `header` only makes sense on mid size screens as additional information is only visible there. For for larger screens, the content of `.more-info` is the page header. On small screens, I don't even know what to put inside a `<h1>`.

I could put the page title in there, but as soon as the page title gets changed to an image (logo or something like that), it's bad markup again.

How should I proceed - have two `header`s on the page? To my knowledge this is allowed, but I am really unsure if it is okay/intended in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you're doing a great job so far with your semantics.

You *can* have multiple `<header>` tags on one page, as the `<header>` tag (and `<footer>` for that matter) just represents the header area for its nearest ancestor section (whether this is literally a `<section>` or in your case a `<main>`).

It's true that if you use a `<nav>` tag in your global header then you're saying that that navigation is your global website navigation. However, whether you hide this at certain breakpoints or not is irrelevant, semantically-speaking.

Semantics are important without a doubt, but I don't think you should view it as the be all and end all of the project, and you certainly shouldn't get stressed about it. Just do your best and know that you can improve it in the future. There are many more important things that you could be spending your time on for your new website, such as page load speed which is becoming more increasingly important in SEO, and also content quality.

For further reading, I'd suggest checking out this article by Smashing Magazine on [SEO for Responsive Websites](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/15/seo-for-responsive-websites/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The article you linked was the most informative read I had in a long time. It's also nice to hear that having good semantics is more of a process then just something you simply do. But I have one question: Are you really sure that if a `header` is directly listed inside `main`, the `header` represents the header for everything in `main`? Because a `section` is sectioning content, while `main` is grouping content and does not introduce a new section.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading Smashing Magazine articles, they're always very well written. Their books are great, too.

That's a very interesting question you asked. As the `main` element is fairly new, there's not much written about it yet. However, you're probably right that a `header` element is more suited to a `section` so maybe you could create a `section` inside of the `main` and put your header in there. It really does depend on the project and like I said, it can always be changed in the future when more is written about the `main` element. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Sven - You are right. The main element is not a sectioning content or sectioning root element, so the header in that case applies to the body element - i.e. the whole page.

Answer (score -2):

You should never have two `header` elements on a page, even though it is possible. The reason for this is that search engines use the `header` to learn more about your page. If you have more than one, they will become confused. This is also why you don't want your nav to be the header, since it does not help search engines learn more about your page. The header element should include the title of your page. Therefore, it is wise to wrap an `h1` element in a header. This element should include your page's name/purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but are you sure this is true? I think you can have as many header elements on a page as you like – you just have to take care in what context. That header's content is also determined by context. See the `article` elements in my Fiddles. They both have a header element with a `h1` inside them, but that `h1` element only marks up the heading for each article.

Comment: You can have as many as you like, but you will be penalized by search engines such as Google, which it is really designed for. As a result, it is best practice to only have one `header` element.